# Maximum Execution Time (max_execution_time) 0 only solution is change the theme

Tags: php, wordpress, max-execution-timeout

My Maximum Execution Time never changes. I don't have a php.ini file but I changed the values in my server. The other WordPress sites on the same server are fine but this site is giving me issues. The only way it works is if I change the theme to a default one. If the theme is the issue I don't understand why it continues even after a fresh install of the theme. 
WordPress is showing a Memory Limit of 256M
but under PHP max limit it is showing 0

```
Version 7.2.15 
Memory Limit (memory_limit) 256M
Maximum Execution Time (max_execution_time) 0
Maximum File Upload Size (upload_max_filesize)  64M
Maximum File Uploads (max_file_uploads) 20
Maximum Post Size (post_max_size)   128M
Maximum Input Variables (max_input_vars)    10000
cURL Enabled    Yes (version 7.64.0)
OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.2q 20 Nov 2018 (268443935)
Mcrypt Enabled  No
Mbstring Enabled    Yes
Loaded Extensions   Core, date, libxml, openssl, pcre, zlib, filter, hash, pcntl, readline, Reflection, SPL, session, standard, cgi-fcgi, bcmath, bz2, calendar, ctype, curl, dba, dom, enchant, mbstring, fileinfo, ftp, gd, gettext, gmp, iconv, imap, intl, json, ldap, exif, mysqlnd, odbc, PDO, pgsql, Phar, posix, pspell, shmop, SimpleXML, snmp, soap, sockets, sqlite3, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm, tidy, tokenizer, xml, xmlwriter, xsl, zip, mysqli, pdo_mysql, PDO_ODBC, pdo_pgsql, pdo_sqlite, wddx, xmlreader, xmlrpc, Zend OPcache
```

Steps I have taken:

Reinstall theme
Reinstall WordPress
Update Server with the latest software
Disabled all plugins

Added this to my Wpconfig.php :
under this /**#@-*/

```
/** Memory Limits. */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
/**
```

Created .user.ini file with these values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 128M
memory_limit = 128M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_vars = 10000
max_input_time = 400
```

The only reason I figured this out is because im using gravity forms and the form kept crashing when I submit it.

Comment: your missing any description of the problem, but have just straight to your -'solutions'

Comment: The problem is I can't change the Maximum Execution Time